# Number formatting in excel in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to export an excel with Springboot using SXSSFWorkbook. But I want to set the cell as numeric, so that when I select the cell, in the format it shows numeric not custom. I also want to add `()` to negative numbers.

I am using a DataFormat of `0.0000` but in excel it is showing as custom format, not numeric. I tried the formats specified in excel in the custom formats for adding the `()`. But they are not working. Please help. Newbie here.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook=new SXSSFWorkbook();
DataFormat deFormatter=workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle cellStyle=workbook.createCellStyle();

//method to set the cell data

{
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(deFormatter.getFormat("0.0000));
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cell.setCellValue(BigDecimal.doubleValue());
}
```

This is a rough idea of the code I have, can't share the exact code because I wrote via a different laptop.

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a custom data format for negative numbers to include parentheses.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat((short) BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("0.0000"));

// adjust for negative numbers with parentheses
DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
String customFormat = "#,##0.0000;(#,##0.0000)";
short customFormatIndex = dataFormat.getFormat(customFormat);
cellStyle.setDataFormat(customFormatIndex);

cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
cell.setCellValue(BigDecimal.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I ended up using at last. It worked, thanks for the answer.